# Need help understanding this code in a tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code randomizes 52 cards and puts 13 each in 4 box of text with every click.  I got the general idea of how it worked, but I need help clearing some confusion or understanding how it worked.  I put bold comments on the ones I am not too sure about.

```
namespace Cards
{
    enum Value { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace}
}
```

---

```
namespace Cards
{
    enum Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades }
}
```

---

```
namespace Cards
{
    class PlayingCard 
    {
        private readonly Suit suit;
        private readonly Value value;

        public PlayingCard(Suit s, Value v)
        {
            this.suit = s;
            this.value = v;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string result = string.Format("{0} of {1}", this.value, this.suit);
            return result;
        }

        public Suit CardSuit() // **Not sure why this is here.  Maybe for future use?**
        {
            return this.suit;
        }

        public Value CardValue() // **Same as above**
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Cards
{
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Pack // **Data Access Layer?**
{
    public const int NumSuits = 4; 
    public const int CardsPerSuit = 13;
    private PlayingCard[,] cardPack;
    private Random randomCardSelector = new Random();

    public Pack() //**Storing all elements**
    {
        this.cardPack = new PlayingCard[NumSuits, CardsPerSuit]; // 

        for (Suit suit = Suit.Clubs; suit <= Suit.Spades; suit++) // 
        {
            for (Value value = Value.Two; value <= Value.Ace; value++)
            {
                this.cardPack[(int)suit, (int)value] = new PlayingCard(suit, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public PlayingCard DealCardFromPack() // **Purpose: To dealing unique cards**
    {
        Suit suit = (Suit)randomCardSelector.Next(NumSuits); // **picks random 0-3 from Suit**
        while (this.IsSuitEmpty(suit)) // **Purpose: Checks if empty but don't know how it works**
        {
            suit = (Suit)randomCardSelector.Next(NumSuits);
        }
        Value value = (Value)randomCardSelector.Next(CardsPerSuit);
        while (this.IsCardAlreadyDealt(suit, value)) // ?
        {
            value = (Value)randomCardSelector.Next(CardsPerSuit);
        }
        PlayingCard card = this.cardPack[(int)suit, (int)value];
        this.cardPack[(int)suit, (int)value] = null; // **sets the current element to null so it isn't reused.**
        return card;
    }

    private bool IsSuitEmpty(Suit suit) // **checks if empty**
    {
        bool result = true;

        for (Value value = Value.Two; value <= Value.Ace; value++) //**Checks Null or not**
        {
            if(!IsCardAlreadyDealt(suit, value))
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private bool IsCardAlreadyDealt(Suit suit, Value value) //**returns current element null?**
    {
        return (this.cardPack[(int)suit, (int)value] == null);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
namespace Cards
{
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Hand // **Business layer?**
{
    public const int HandSize = 13;
    private PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[HandSize]; // **single array?  Thought it had to be 2 because of 2 parameters?**
    private int playingCardCount = 0;

    public void AddCardToHand(PlayingCard cardDealt)//**Confusion when class used as variable**
    {
        if (this.playingCardCount >= HandSize)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Too many cards");
        }
        this.cards[this.playingCardCount] = cardDealt; //**Confused...cardDealt value going in card[]?  How does that work..**
        this.playingCardCount++;//**incrementing, how is this helpful**
    }

    public override string ToString()  //to show all 13 cards in hand
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (PlayingCard card in this.cards)
        {
            result += card.ToString() + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
namespace Cards
{
    public partial class Game : Window
    {
        public const int NumHands = 4;

        private Pack pack = null;
        private Hand[] hands = {new Hand(), new Hand(), new Hand(), new Hand()}; //**Creates 4 different list all single array?**

        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dealClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                pack = new Pack(); 

                for (int handNum = 0; handNum < NumHands; handNum++) //
                {
                    hands[handNum] = new Hand();
                    for (int numCards = 0; numCards < Hand.HandSize; numCards++)
                    {
                        PlayingCard cardDealt = pack.DealCardFromPack(); //**Deals 13 random cards into each array.  Don't understand how it worked though.**
                        hands[handNum].AddCardToHand(cardDealt);
                    }
                }

                north.Text = hands[0].ToString();
                south.Text = hands[1].ToString();
                east.Text = hands[2].ToString();
                west.Text = hands[3].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comments don't 'bold' very well.

Comment: Asking your questions as **comments** within the code is really bad. Looks like you didn't ask anything. Do us and yourself a favour and post your questions **outside** of the code sections.

Comment: Anyway, for starters, if you don't know what `class something {..}` does, you might want to go back a few pages in the tutorial and read up on classes.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. You aren't looking for an essay on every one of your highlighted comments, I hope.

Comment: That is a lot of questions for one post. I think the best thing to do is focus on a smaller area of the code and question in a single post. Otherwise, the answers will be incomplete or too long to follow easily.

Comment: If I understood the code correctly, it is NOT random, at least not an equal chance for each card like it should be.

Comment: Ok I will be reposting this in a different way

Comment: You can edit the post without having to create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PlayingCard**:

```
class PlayingCard // **Data Access Layer?**
```

This looks like a business model, nothing to do with data access.  In fact, I don't see any data persistence (like a database) being used in the code at all, so this application doesn't have a data access layer.

```
private readonly Suit suit; // **readonly to protect from changing value?**
```

Correct.  This makes the value "immutable" in that it can't be changed once the object is constructed.  Note that this value is set in (and *only* in) the class' constructor.  So to have a different `suit` one needs to construct a different instance of the class (a different object, as it were).

```
public PlayingCard(Suit s, Value v) //**Returning value of every card**
```

Not really.  This is the constructor for the class.  Any time a new instance of the class is created (for example, `var card = new PlayingCard(someSuit, someValue)`), this method executes to construct that instance.

```
public Suit CardSuit() // **Not sure why this is here.  Maybe for future use?**
```

This is a method to get the value of the current `Suit` for that card.  So something using the card can see what suit it is.  Note that the value it's returning is `private` so it can't otherwise be read from outside the class.  (I disagree with this implementation and would prefer a property instead of a method, but that's another subject entirely.)

**Pack**:

```
class Pack // **Data Access Layer?**
```

Nope, same as before.  These are models.  I'll get to that in a bit.

```
public Pack() //**Storing all elements**
```

Constructor again, same as before.

```
public PlayingCard DealCardFromPack() // **Purpose: To dealing unique cards**
```

Yes.  This is a logical method to have on a `Pack` object.  One can reasonably expect that a `Pack` can be used to deal `PlayingCard`s.  That is, they can be extracted from the `Pack`.  So that's what this method is for.

```
Suit suit = (Suit)randomCardSelector.Next(NumSuits); // **picks random 0-3 from Suit**
```

Yup, chooses a random `Suit` from the given enumeration of known `Suit`s.

```
while (this.IsSuitEmpty(suit)) // **Purpose: Checks if empty but don't know how it works**
```

Well, a pack doesn't have an infinite number of cards.  Every time one is removed, it's deleted from the class that's holding the cards (the `Pack`).  So it can't very well deal from a suit for which it no longer has cards.  Thus, this checks to see if there are still cards left in the suit before trying to deal one.

```
this.cardPack[(int)suit, (int)value] = null; // **sets the current element to null so it isn't reused.**
```

Yup, this is related to the previous part.  When a card is dealt, it's removed.  So this "deletes" it from the `Pack`.

```
private bool IsSuitEmpty(Suit suit) // **checks if empty**
```

This is a kind of helper method within the class.  The method which deals out the cards needs to check if the suit is empty, so this method was written to make that check.  (Rather than have all of the code in one big method, which would be poor design.)

```
private bool IsCardAlreadyDealt(Suit suit, Value value) //**returns current element null?**
```

This is another helper method.  When dealing cards, one can't deal a card that's already been dealt.  So this checks for that.  So basically, the larger method which uses these methods is saying: "While randomly looking at suits, I need a suit that still has cards.  While randomly looking at cards in that suit, I need a card that's still in the deck.  Now remove that card from the deck."

**Hand**:

```
class Hand // **Business layer?**
```

Kind of.  Sort of.  It's another model.  I'll get to that in a second.

```
private PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[HandSize]; // **single array?  Thought it had to be 2 because of 2 parameters?**
```

What 2 parameters?  It's an array of cards.  Each `Hand` is basically a collection of cards.  This stores references to those cards.

```
public void AddCardToHand(PlayingCard cardDealt)//**Confusion when class used as variable**
```

I'm not sure what you're asking in the comment.  The purpose of this method is to add a card to the hand.  So a reference to a card is passed to the method, and the method adds it to the current hand.

```
this.cards[this.playingCardCount] = cardDealt; //**Confused...cardDealt value going in card[]?  How does that work..**
```

In this case, `cardDealt` is the card that was given to the `Hand` to be added.  It has nothing to do with the "dealt" concept in the previous class.  It's just the name of the variable.  What this line is doing is adding that card to the array of cards in the `Hand`.

```
this.playingCardCount++;//**incrementing, how is this helpful**
```

The hand is now larger by one card.  So if you added, say, the third card to the hand, it would be added as `this.cards[2]`.  Adding another card to the hand after that needs to go in `this.cards[3]`, otherwise it would replace an existing card, which isn't the desired effect.

```
public override string ToString()  //to show all 13 cards in hand
```

Correct, this method is just to print out what's currently in the `Hand`.

---

**Conclusion**:

Ok, now that we've gone through that exercise (and feel free to ask for clarification), let's talk for a moment about what a "model" is.  It's kind of a business layer in that it's a "business object."  That is, it's an object which encapsulates a business concept.

In the case of this application, there are three concrete concepts which represent the "business" of dealing cards to a hand.  These are:

- A card
- A deck, which contains a pre-determined finite list of cards
- A hand, which contains a list of cards given to it

Each model has the responsibility to internally maintain its business logic.  This is done with its internal variables, properties, methods, etc.  Things like `DealCardFromDeck` are real-world concepts of how the business works which are encoded into the models.  The other models don't care how that model implements that business logic, they just know that one can deal a card from a deck.  (This is part of the model's externally-visible interface to other models.)

The business logic (business layer, if you will, although this code snipped doesn't really have "layers" per se) is seen in how the models interact with one another.  At its simplest, my list of the three models above basically describes how they interact.  The code is just an implementation of that logic.

Comment: @healxph0enix: Glad to help, it was actually kind of a fun answer to write :)  Needless to say, there's a lot to be learned.  But I actually like this code as an example of a simple domain model.  Where did you get this code?

Comment: Visual c# 2010 step by step ebook tutorial.  I get most of it now, and I need to review some things haha.

Comment: I am confused on Class Hand

In AddCardToHand method.  I understand now it adds 13 cards to your hand.  I am confused on variable cardDealt(I believe this is a reference).  How is it figuring out what card to put into cards.

Comment: @healxph0enix: In that method, `cardDealt` is the variable that gets passed into the method.  This happens in the `Game` class when it says: `hands[handNum].AddCardToHand(cardDealt);`.  The line just before that gets a card from the pack and assigns it to a variable, then this line passes that variable into the method.  (It's only a coincidence that the name of the variable is the same in `Game` as it is in `AddCardToHand`, they don't need to be the same.  In fact, I would have preferred if it had a different name in `AddCardToHand`, since that method shouldn't care where the card came from.)

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer:

Card, Pack and Hand are *not* part of the Data Access Layer. They are the model (object/entity/domain model) of the application.

If you have code to Save/Load any of these to a Db or a File than that code would be the DAL.

```
 private readonly Suit suit; // **readonly to protect from changing value?**
 private readonly Value value;
```

Yes, readonly because once a Card exists it should never change. That would upset the logic (and honesty) of the game. Building that notion into the model is a good idea.

```
    public PlayingCard(Suit s, Value v) //**Returning value of every card**
```

This is not returning anything, it is a *constructor* of the PlayingCard class.

```
    public Suit CardSuit() // **Not sure why this is here.  Maybe for future use?**
```

No, not for 'future use'. It is very essential part of the class that lets other code find out which card it is. Note that the readonly field `suit` is private.

Answer (score 0):

Question: // **Data Access Layer?**

Answer: No. This is a class that models a single card

---

Question: // **Business layer?**

Answer: No. This is a class that model a collection of cards.

Comment: The Hand _is_ the business layer in a card game.

Answer (score 0):

The code is self explanatory. I guess you need to dig a little deeper into knowing how to program, for example:

- Read only variables are used that way because their values can only be set on the constructor of the class.
- the method you say it returns the value of every card is actually the constructor and it is used to assign the suit and value of the card.
- the CardSuit() and CardValue() methods return the current suit and value values for a card.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the stuff is basic C# that a decent programmer should recognize right away. The algorithm for dealing a random card is flawed. Here is the outline:

Select a random suit.

If all the cards of that suit have been dealt already, go to step 1.

Select a random rank.

If the card of the selected suit and rank has been dealt already, go to step 3.

Remove the selected card from the deck.

Deal it.

The reason that this is flawed is best illustrated with this example. The following cards are left in the deck (2C = 2 of clubs):

2C 2S 3S 4S

In real life the chance of dealing the 2 of clubs would be 1/4. With this algorithm, it is 1/2, because it has an equal chance of choosing to deal a club as it does a spade. Think of it as splitting the deck into 4 piles and randomly choosing a pile to deal from. Each pile represents a suit. This is not the way to do it.

I give you the permission to look down on the writer of this code. Oh, and find a better book.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public Suit CardSuit() // **Not sure why this is here.  Maybe for future use?**
    {
        return this.suit;
    }

    public Value CardValue() // **Same as above**
    {
        return this.value;
    }
```

These methods are commonly referred to as "getters". When called, these methods return a piece of the internal state (variables) of the class. Programmers commonly add them to a call, even there is no immediate use for them.

Honestly, I think an introductory book on C# would serve you better than Stack Overflow.